# Como llamar un programa desde otro programa con un boton en pythom

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero realizar un programa el cual estará hecho en python y usara tkinter, busco tener una interfaz y al presionar un botón esta se cierre y llame a otro programa (otra interfaz). He buscado información y hecho unos programas de prueba pero no puedo lograr que se ejecute el segundo programa. Alguien sabrá como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Porque no usas el modulo [subprocess](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-subprocess-to-run-external-programs-in-python-3-es)?

Comment: Al utilizar el subprocess el programa que lo llamo se cerraría? o se quedaria abierto?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.